# most efficient way to find differences?

Tags: r, loops, array-difference

Very simple question and I regret having to ask it on SO. I'm hoping a creative mind out there has a better solution than I have thought of.

I want to find the differences between adjacent values of a matrix where the value for "type" is the same. For the below example, I would want a vector with the values 2,6,1.

```
mat
     value type
[1,]  5   A
[2,]  7   A
[3,]  1   B
[4,]  2   C
[5,]  8   C
[6,]  9   C
```

I have tried implementing it in two ways, but both of them are quite slow:

- Approach 1: If `type(row 1) = type(row 2)`, then find `value(row 2) - value(row 1)`, then increment by one. If `type(row 1) != type(row 2)`, then increment by 2.
- Approach 2: Loop through each different `type` and find all differences.

There are about 500,000 different "types" and 5 million different rows.  Can anyone think of a more efficient way? I am programming in the language R, where there is already a function to find the differences for me (see: ?diff).

Comment: I am not sure your output 2, 6, 1 concurs with what you are saying what you want to do.

Comment: sorry for any confusion. To clarify, I will only want differences in values if there are two or more rows of the same "type".

Comment: Why a flat structure when you want something more composite? Maybe something like a map of arrays with types as keys?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, rather than pseudocode. This is an optimization question, which can't really be answered without the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you have too many rows to do this, I'll suggest a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df) # where `df` is your data.frame

DT[, diff(value), by=type]$V1
# [1] 2 6 1
```

---

#### Simulating this code on a data of your dimensions:

It takes close to 20 seconds (bottleneck should be calls to `diff`) on data of your dimensions.

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(45)
types <- sapply(1:5e5, function(x) paste0(sample(letters, 5, TRUE), collapse=""))

DT <- data.table(value=sample(100, 5e6, TRUE), type=sample(types, 5e6, TRUE))
system.time(t1 <- DT[, diff(value), by=type]$V1)
#   user  system elapsed 
# 18.610   0.238  19.166
```

To compare against the other answer with `tapply`:

```
system.time(t2 <- tapply(DT[["value"]], DT[["type"]], diff))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 48.471   0.664  51.673
```

Also, `tapply` orders the results by `type` where as `data.table` without `key` will preserve the original order.

---

**Edit:** Following @eddi's comment:

```
> system.time(t3 <- DT[, value[-1]-value[-.N], by=type]$V1)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 6.221   0.195   6.641
```

There's a 3x improvement by removing the call to `diff`. Thanks @eddi.

Comment: wow, this not only works but is also very fast. Great solution, thank you so much.

Comment: replace `diff(value)` with `value[-1] - value[-.N]` to get ~4x speed improvement

Comment: @eddi: That's pretty slick!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tapply(mat[["value"]], mat[["type"]], diff)
```

Then you can `unlist` your result to get it in a tidier format.